# check index value of multi-value parameter

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a multi-value parameter how I check in iif condition that value of idex is null or not
now, I am using this expression

> IIF(IsNothing(Parameters!FR.Value(0))," ","Test")

My parameter is hidden and some thing it has 4 values or some time less than 4.

when I check that values of index 3 value(3) and there is no value in this index. I shows error. How I check the index value of parameter.

Comment: I think this could also be of some use:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237135/display-the-non-selected-parameter-in-ssrs/21240183#21240183

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem is that there is no object at index 3, not that the value of the object is `Nothing`, so you will get an error trying to access the `Value` property of an object that doesn't exist.

The second problem is that `IIF` is a function not a language construct, so all parameters are  evaluated before the function is called regardless of the value of the boolean condition. I can't see a way of trying to access the `Value(3)` property without the `IIF` function blowing up in your face when it doesn't exist. You could try something convoluted like this:

```
=IIF(Parameters!FR.Count >= 4, Parameters!FR.Value(IIF(Parameters!FR.Count >= 4, 3, 0)), "")
```

but that is *still* going to blow up in your face when there are no parameter values selected at all.

The easiest and safest way to do it would be to create a custom code function to which you pass the multi-value parameter and the index you want:

```
Function Get_FR_by_Index(ByVal parameter As Parameter, ByVal index As Integer) AS String
  Dim Result As String
  Result = ""
  If parameter.IsMultiValue Then
    If parameter.Count >= index+1 Then
      Result = CStr(parameter.Value(index))
    End If 
  End If 

  Return Result
End Function
```

then use this function to access the result:

```
=Code.Get_FR_by_Index(Parameters!FR, 3)
```

Remember that the index is zero-based, so the first `Value` is index 0.

Comment: Hi Chris,
thanks for your reply. I want to ask that  where I write this function in ssrs report.

Comment: In Visual Studio, use the `Report` menu and select `Report Properties...`. On that dialogue box select the `Code` window and paste the code above. You will then be able to access the code  in your expression as described.